Azure DevOps pipeline is throwing a "##[error]Project file(s) matching the specified pattern were not found". when publishing my app?
My Azure DevOps pipeline is throwing

##[error]Project file(s) matching the specified pattern were not found'

when publishing my app!
Here is a portion of the azure-pipelines.yml specifically the "Publish" task for the project.
...

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  name: "Publish"
  displayName: "Publish"
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: '$(Parameters.projects)'
    arguments: '--configuration: $(BuildConfiguration) --output: 
$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    zipAfterPublish: false

...


Starting: Publish
=================================================================
Task         : .NET Core
Description  : Build, test, package, or publish a dotnet application, or run a custom dotnet command
Version      : 2.238.1
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : 



[dotnet-core-cli][1]
=================================================================
C:\Windows\system32\chcp.com 65001
Active code page: 65001
Info: .NET Core SDK/runtime 2.2 and 3.0 are now End of Life(EOL) 
and have been removed from all hosted agents. If you're using these SDK/runtimes on hosted agents, kindly upgrade to newer versions which are not EOL, or else use UseDotNet task to install the required version.
Info: Azure Pipelines hosted agents have been updated and now contain .Net 5.x SDK/Runtime along with the older .Net Core version which are currently lts. Unless you have locked down a SDK version for your project(s), 5.x SDK might be picked up which might have breaking behavior as compared to previous versions. You can learn more about the breaking changes here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/ and https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/ . To learn about more such changes and troubleshoot, refer here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops#troubleshooting
##[error]Project file(s) matching the specified pattern were not found.
Finishing: Publish



Can you share some details about the task to publish your app? The dotnet publish task will generate the files you need to publish. Are you getting the error in dotnet publish task?

@KevinLu-MSFT I'm not quite sure what you mean, but I'll update the post with some more detail! Please let me know if this helps. I'm getting the error when running the pipeline in Azure DevOps.

You can share some pipeline error log. It should be helpful.

Please refer to my answer and do changes in the projects filed of the dotnet publish task. Then you can check if it can work as expected.

Or you can hard code the path to the .csproj file in the projects field according to your actual file structure.

@KevinLu-MSFT Thanks I'm updating my solution to check if the pipeline changes you mentioned will work for me.

No Problem. Feel free to share the result with us. If the issue still exists, I will check this issue furhter.

@KevinLu-MSFT Thanks changing the projects value from projects: '$(Parameters.projects)' to projects: '**/*.csproj' seemed to do the trick. Thanks very much for your help.

From your dotnet publish task definition, the cause of the issue could be that the projects field(projects: '$(Parameters.projects)') has issue.
You need to set the correct .csproj file path in the project field of dotnet publish task.
If you are using the YAML Pipeline, you can use the following format in the projects field: **/*.csproj
For example:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  name: "Publish"
  displayName: "Publish"
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration: $(BuildConfiguration) --output:$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    zipAfterPublish: false

If you are using classic pipeline, you can refer to the following steps to unlink the parameter and set the correct value.
Step1: Navigate to Pipelines tab and unlink the parameters.
For example:

Step2: Set the **/*.csproj in dotnet publish task.
For example:

